# How do I change a class when a link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I would like to change the background position of an image link upon onClick.  I would call this the "active" class.  Using jQuery, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.active').click(function() {
  $('.active').css('background-position', value);
});
```

there's also add/removeClass and toggleClass methods available with jquery assuming you have a css class with the background-position already set

http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

Comment: Question is asking for changing a class.

Answer (score 0):

Using background-position property:

```
$("a.imageLink").click
(
 function()
 {
  $(this).css("background-position", "YOUR_IMAGE_X_POSITION YOUR_IMAGE_Y_POSITION")
 }
)
```

Using class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .leftIMG
    {
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-image: URL("YOUR_IMAGE");
    }

    .rightIMG
    {
        background-position: 100 0;
        background-image: URL("YOUR_IMAGE");
    }
</style>

$("a.imageLink").click
(
 function()
 {
    var a = $(this);
    if(a.hasClass("rightIMG"))
    {
        a.addClass("leftIMG").removeClass("rightIMG");
    }
    else
    {
        a.addClass("rightIMG").removeClass("leftIMG");
    }
 }
)
```

Comment: Question is asking for changing a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$('yourselector').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

If you don't:

```
var addActiveClass = function() {
    this.className += ' active';
};
if(el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener('click', addActiveClass, false);
} else if(el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('onclick', addActiveClass);
} else {
    var cachedOnClick;
    if(el.onclick) {
        cachedOnClick = el.onclick;
    }
    el.onclick = function(e) {
        if(cachedOnClick !== undefined) {
            cachedOnClick.call(this, e);
        }
        addActiveClass.call(this);
    };
}
```